# LinqPad adds an S to the end of every table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have just downloaded LinqPad to explore the benefits of using Linq queries in an application I am working on, however when I look at my database tables in the column on the left LinqPad displays all my tables with an 's' on the end, for instance CategoryTbl becomes CategoryTbls yet when I view my database in SQL management studio the table names appear correct.

Though any tables that should have an S on the end ie clients remain unchanged.

When I execute a Linq query I have to execute it against CategoryTbls but a SQL query has to be executed against CategoryTbl.

I was just wondering why this has happened, is it a bug or a feature? and if it is a feature why?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first question from the [LINQPad FAQ](http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx):

> **Why does LINQPad pluralize table and child association properties? Can I switch this off?**
>
> Pluralizing child association properties (while keeping parent associations singular) makes for the most natural queries and is what Visual Studio does by default in building typed DataContexts.
>
> To switch off pluralization, uncheck the "Pluralize" option when adding the database connection. (If the connection has already been created, right-click it to edit the connection properties).

Comment: Thanks, lol I didnt think of the FAQ, googled this a fair bit and the error message I was getting but got some fairly generic results.

Answer (score 4):

This is also the standard behaviour of LINQ2SQL generated artifacts - the IEnumerables on the DataContext are [TableName]s and the Entity is [TableName]. So your linq queries would typically be something like.

```
List<Category> categoryList = context.Categories.Where(cat => somePredicateOnCat).ToList();
```

This usually makes for intuitive reading.
Would you consider dropping the Hungarian 'tbl' suffix off your table naming standards?