# Steps for a beginner to run very basic linq to sql query using Linqpad

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

Trying to learn Linq using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and getting frustated with how to start on it. Let's say I want to write a C# Expression and a C# statment where I have a table in SQL server named Products and I want to pull all rows where price is greater then 50. How would yo write it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Let's say I want to write a C# Expression and a C# statment where I
>   have a table in SQL server named Products and I want to pull all rows
>   where price is greater then 50. How would yo write it?

LINQPad builds the typed DataContext for you automatically, so you don't need to instantiate anything. In C# expression mode, just type the folowing:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Price > 50)
```

and press F5. Alternatively, you might prefer to use a query expression:

```
from p in Products
where p.Price > 50
select p
```

In C# statements mode, you'll need to call the Dump() method to tell it to write out the results. You'll also need to terminate the expression with a semicolon:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Price > 50).Dump();
```

There are more examples in the samples section of LINQPad - look at the 5-minute induction.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. That's exactly what i was looking for. BTW exprssion worked fine but when I run "from p in Products where p.Price > 50 select p" statment I get error "; expected". I add ; at end but that does not help either. Any ideas?

Comment: that's because you've got C# Statement(s) selected. Statements must end with ; but expressions cannot end with ; I just skip all this confusion and go with C# Program :)

Comment: @Joe can you help me with this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291255/linqpad-doesnt-render-group-collection

Comment: @alex-v-kostyukov, i think you meant to ask @ joe-albahari and not @ joe. it's a bit confusing because he answered the question but I commented on it and it appears we are the same person. Compounded by the fact that my username is joe :) I was here first!

Answer (score 12):

Just wanted to add - LINQ pad pluralizes - I did not know this and it drove me crazy for a good fifteen minutes

I was trying to select from a table called DentalApplication

```
    DentalApplication.Where(a=> a.PackageID > 0)
```

Gave me this error

```
    'LINQPad.User.DentalApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Where'
```

Changed it to

```
    DentalApplications.Where(a=> a.PackageID > 0)
```

and it worked

Comment: For default, Linqpad pluralizing child association properties.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833133/linqpad-adds-an-s-to-the-end-of-every-table

Answer (score 3):

```
var db = new MyDatabaseContext();  // Your database context.
var result = db.Products.Where(q=>q.Price > 50);
```

...where `db` represents your ORM context. `Price` represents your mapping to the `Price` field in the database.  `result` represents the result set -- your database rows/entities.

Comment: It gives "The type or namespace name 'MyDatabaseContext' could not be found". Sorry for my ignorance but I am totally new to Linq/ORM. Do i need to setup something in Linqpad? My impression that I can just use linq to sql just like I use my SQL management studio and directly query database tables

Comment: You need to create a database mapping.  `MyDatabaseContext` just is a dummy name for whatever you called your ORM.

Comment: Do you know where exactly can I create mapping in LinqPad?

Comment: Reading the link at http://blog.trekforth.com/2009/07/querying-sql-with-linqpad.html, does not seem like i need to create any mapping

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933(v=vs.90).aspx which will give you an introduction to Linq and using lambda expressions.

Then have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927.aspx which will give you the basics, but to answer your specific question:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(prod => prod.Price > 50);
foreach(var product in products)
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: When I run it as a C# program, i get following error "'LINQPad.User.Products' does not contain a definition for 'Price' and no extension method 'Price' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQPad.User.Products' could be found". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to create a database mapping.  Did you have a look at the Linq 2 SQL tutorial link I posted?  That covers the basics.  Do you have a database set up with a products table?

Comment: Yeah I have seen that but In LinqPad the only option i seem to find is Add Connection. Once I added connection to my SQL Server db instance, i can see  all databases/tables etc on left side. I just don't know or see any optons how and where to create database mapping

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with LinqPad.