# Convert Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have researched on the net and most result are converting from sql to linq and seldom have linq to sql.

this is the code which I want to convert to SQL :

```
 using (CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities())
    {
    try
      {
      var query = (from ProductOrders in db.OrderDetails
                        join SelectedProducts in db.Products on ProductOrders.ProductID  
                        equals SelectedProducts.ProductID
                        group ProductOrders by new
                            {
                            ProductId = SelectedProducts.ProductID,
                            ModelName = SelectedProducts.ModelName
                            } into grp
                        select new
                            {
                            ModelName = grp.Key.ModelName,
                            ProductId = grp.Key.ProductId,
                            Quantity = grp.Sum(o => o.Quantity)
                            } into orderdgrp where orderdgrp.Quantity > 0 
                        orderby orderdgrp.Quantity descending select orderdgrp).Take(5);

                    RepeaterItemsList.DataSource = query;
                    RepeaterItemsList.DataBind(); 
      }
    catch (Exception exp)
      {
      throw new Exception("ERROR: Unable to Load Popular Items - " + 
                           exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can always use the profiler to look at the actual query produced, or plug in some form of logging.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL server inside Microsoft visual studio.

Comment: Why don't you try Linqpad, it will help you to understand things and you can see the sql generated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attempt to run the LINQ statement in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). For examples on how to use LinqPad, [check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003761/19582).

It has a tab to show the generated SQL statement.

Comment: I had download the LinqPad, but how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an article on logging in LINQ to SQL](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers). It lets you specify a TextWriter to which to send the query.

Basically, you can write something like this:

```
db.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("linq-to-sql.log") { AutoFlush = true };
```

... where `db` is your data context.

In SQL you'd write something like this (although the produced code will look a lot different, since it is auto-generated):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Products.ModelName, Products.ProductID, SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) qty
FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY Products.ProductID, Products.ModelName
HAVING qty > 0
ORDER BY qty DESC
```